# QueryDsl how to use exist() to return boolean

Tags: java, querydsl

I want to upgrade queryDsl from verision 3 to version 4.
But i've an issue with exist()
In QueryDsl 3 exist return a Boolean but  in QUeryDSL 4 it return a BooleanOperation.
In my case i really want the boolean but i don't know how to retrieve it.

The best solution i've found is to do

```
.fetchCount() >0
```

But I want to know if another (better) solution exist.

Answer (score 1):

Another option would be something like:

```
queryFactory.select(queryField).from(qTable)
            .where(queryField.eq(value))
            .groupBy(queryField)
            .having(qTable.uuid.count().gt(0))
            .fetchOne() != null;
```

This passes the greater than responsibility over to the query. However it is possibly less readible so will depend on the requirements which is better.